# What is a replacement for AnalyzeAsync in NEST 7.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I update my app from Nest version 6.8 to 7.3, and found, that AnalyzeAsync method currently not supported. What is a replacement for the following code?

```
var analyzeRequest = new AnalyzeRequest(_elasticSearchSettings.PatentFamilyIndexName)
            {
                Analyzer = analyzer,
                Text = new[] {wordsList}
            };
var analyzeResponse = await ElasticClient.AnalyzeAsync(analyzeRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NEST 7.x, API methods have been grouped under the area of functionality that thery're related to

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var analyzeRequest = new AnalyzeRequest(_elasticSearchSettings.PatentFamilyIndexName)
{
    Analyzer = analyzer,
    Text = new[] { wordsList }
};

var analyzeResponse = await client.Indices.AnalyzeAsync(analyzeRequest);
```

This aligns NEST with the grouping in the REST API specs, as well as other clients. You can [read more about the changes in the 7.x release blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-7-0-now-ga).